# problem with multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python

```
x=int(raw_input("Enter first number"))
y=int(raw_input("Enter second number"))
```

I do not understand why I am unable to post this into my Python 3.8.2 shell? Does anyone have any advice on an alternative way?

Thanks.

Comment: Paste one, then enter the number. Paste the second, then enter that number.
Both statements are expecting an input and you aren't giving one between them

Comment: To be clear, this is a problem with your terminal/shell, not Python itself. For example IPython doesn't have this problem and I get a totally different error in Gnome Terminal. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` is python2 syntax and you should use.`input`.

it was renamed in python 3, refer to the following link: 
http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html

change to:

```
x=int(input("Enter first number"))
y=int(input("Enter second number"))
```

Regarding the issue of pasting both in the terminal, you should read about the `input` function and you'll see that once it's called it waits for an input and is something was pasted it will take it as an input.